# golang reflection to set first value of a struct to its zero value

Tags: go, reflection

go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ck3PtydW3YT

I have a struct like:

```
type Input struct {
    InputA *InputA
    InputB *InputB
    InputC *InputC
}
```

I'm trying to use reflection to set the first value (in this case, *InputA) to its zero value (&InputA{}), but it's not working:

```
    actionInput = Input{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(actionInput)

    i := 0
    typ := v.Field(i).Type()

    inputStruct := reflect.New(typ).Elem().Interface()

    reflect.ValueOf(&actionInput).Elem().Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(inputStruct))
```

I'm guessing this is because it's a pointer, but I'm not sure how to work around that

Comment: You are setting the first field to its zero value. The zero value for a pointer is nil. If you need to set it to a pointer pointing to the zero value of the struct, you have to create a new instance of that struct, get a pointer to that, and set that instead.

Comment: That's what I tried doing when defining `inputStruct`, but apparently this creates a new "*InputA", not a new "InputA". This makes sense, but I don't know how to fix this to my intent.

Comment: If you want a new `InputA` that would be `reflect.New(v.Field(i).Elem().Type()).Interface()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work. If the field is a pointer, it creates an instance of the type pointed to by that pointer, and sets that.

```
    typ := v.Field(i).Type()
    var inputStruct reflect.Value
    if typ.Kind()==reflect.Ptr {
       inputStruct=reflect.New(typ.Elem())
    } else {
        inputStruct = reflect.New(typ).Elem()
    }

    reflect.ValueOf(&actionInput).Elem().Field(i).Set(inputStruct)
```